# How to change size of a menu item in Android Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

How to change size of a menu item in Android Toolbar? I have a button, which is an image and I want to have it bigger than it is now.

Example screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygdeb.png

Comment: Easiest way is to provide bigger images

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is just Android's new Action Bar

http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Simply, you can use this with AppCompat v21 library included in your project:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id=”@+id/my_awesome_toolbar”
    android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:minHeight=”?attr/actionBarSize”
    android:background=”?attr/colorPrimary”>
     <--Your UI elements here-->
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```